# Leap year EOM excel formula

Tags: excel, formulas

I am trying to extract one year from this date 29/02/2020 and should be getting this 28/02/2019, but I am getting this 31/03/2019. I have the following formula =TEXT(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(G1)-1,MONTH(G1),DAY(G1)),0),"DD/MM/YYYY"), can someone tell me what I need to add to this formula so that it takes into account leap years.

Answer (score 2):

Would this be okay with you:

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH(G1,-12),"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

Comment: will this take into consideration all  leap years and any other dates

Comment: You could try it and see. One would assume it would do so, since it was posted as an answer, to a question in which you specifically asked for that.

Comment: It will if you are looking for end of month, which is defined in your question.